# Merging declarations of namespace and variable

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to create declaration file for a third-party library `node-tap`. The simplified problem is: for a library

```
// node_modules/a/index.js
function A() { /* ... */ }
module.exports = new A();
module.exports.A = A;
```

what would be a correct `*.d.ts` declaration file to allow the following code to compile successfully?

```
// test.ts
import * as a from 'a';
import {A} from 'a';
function f(): A {
    return a;
}
```

Mention that having `A` as type is important, even though it could be omitted in this simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to be able to call `new a.A()`, do:

```
declare class A {
    A: typeof A;
}
declare const a: A;
declare namespace a {
    export type A = A;
}
export = a;
```

If you only need the type `a.A` accessible, do:

```
declare const a: a.A;
declare namespace a {
    interface A {}
}
export = a
```

Comment: I think you need to keep `declare class A { A: typeof A }`, otherwise you can't do `new a.A()`, as `a.A` only refers to a type.